# How do I download pages from a site that aren't linked?

Tags: wget

I am trying to mirror the entire site "citypaper.com" using wget
At first all it would do is download the index.html and stop. 
Then I found the solution:
wget -r -p -e robots=off http://www.citypaper.com
Now it downloads pages that are linked to index.html as well as pages linked to those, and so on...
The problem is that there are thousands of pages that are no longer actually on any of these pages. 
Is there a way for wget to download these pages as well?

Answer (score 0):

What you want is a web crawler i think. You can start with some tool like this to get a feel
https://www.screamingfrog.co.uk/crawl-javascript-seo/